# Switching to assigning functions to objects on windows.onload rather than explicitly. Experiencing difficulties

Tags: javascript, function, dom

[Utitlizing Visual Studio ASP.Net with C# on ie]

I have been attempting to switch away from explicitly assigning events on my objects, to move towards Unobtrusive JavaScript. However, I can't seem to find proper information on how to begin.

My functions are located in the head and work well. I am trying to add window.onload to the head as well.

```
    window.onload = myOnloadFunc()
{
document.getElementById('<%= NewQuestionTopbtn %>').OnClientClick="return NewQuestion()";
}
```

When I debug, I immediately get the error, "Microsoft JScript runtime error: Object expected"
Then my dynamic code displays:

```
  window.onload = myOnloadFunc()
{
document.getElementById('System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button').OnClientClick="return NewQuestion()";
}
```

Leading me to believe that the windows.onload function appears to be running before the DOM is loaded. However, I was lead to believe that the window.onload function ran after the page was loaded.

My button works fine when using:

```
<asp:Button ID="NewQuestionTopbtn" runat="server" Font-Bold="True" Font-Size="Medium" Text="New Question"  
OnClientClick="return NewQuestion()"/>
```

Any advice is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing the function keyword. You'll also want to use the ClientID which is the ID that is used on the HTML element for the browser client.

```
  window.onload = function()
{
   document.getElementById('<%= NewQuestionTopbtn.ClientID %>').addEventListener("click",NewQuestion);
}
```

Comment: Glanced over what I copied and pasted. See my update, you need to use the clientID. getElementByID was returning null.

Comment: Good call! However, I had to use attachEvent: "document.getElementById('<%= NewQuestionTopbtn.ClientID %>').attachEvent("onclick", NewQuestion);" I researched addEventListener at http://quirksmode.org/js/events_advanced.html  THANK YOU VERY MUCH